# Change UILabel background color

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

my code is

```
UILabel *pTeamAlreadybl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 275,180,30)];

pTeamAlreadybl.text=@" Team already?";
pTeamAlreadybl.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
pTeamAlreadybl.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
pTeamAlreadybl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255.0 green:61.0/255.0 blue:61.0/255.0 alpha:0.6];
pTeamAlreadybl.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.7];
```

How can I change label's background color?

Answer (score 6):

You miss

```
pTeamAlreadybl.backgroundColor=[UIColor anycolor];
```

write this code

Answer (score 5):

To change the background color of a **UILabel**, you need to set the **backgroundColor** property of the UILabel object. You can do so by using the following line of code:

```
[pTeamAlreadybl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorOfYourChoice]];
```

OR

```
pTeamAlreadybl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorOfYourChoice];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pTeamAlreadybl.backgroundColor = [UIColor ...];
```

Doesn't the above code work?

Answer (score 0):

```
[pTeamAlreadybl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor YourColor]];
```

YourColor as mentioned below

blackColor;
darkGrayColor;
lightGrayColor
whiteColor;
grayColor;
redColor;
greenColor;
blueColor;
cyanColor;
yellowColor;
magentaColor; 
orangeColor;
purpleColor;
brownColor;
clearColor;

you can use customized color as well like this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255.0 green:61.0/255.0 blue:61.0/255.0 alpha:0.6]
```